# Get the min value of one variable greater than the observation of another variable

Tags: r

I have two different datasets (or vectors). Let's say in one I have this variable with several observations:

```
a<- c(1:30)
```

Then in the other dataset I have another (much smaller variable) with let's say only 5 observations.

```
ref <- c(5:10)
```

I want to create a variable that contains the minimum value of ref among those greater (or equal) than a, for each a, or else produce 0. I tried this, but obviously does not work.

```
min <- ifelse(a>=ref, min(ref[a>=ref]), 0)
```

The outcome variable should have the same length as a, and be 0 when a is between 1 and 4, 5 when it's 5, 6 when it's 6... and 10 for all values 10 or above.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So what should it be when `a` is 15? 0 or 10? Other than your last sentence, sounds like 0.

Comment: Do you need `replace(findInterval(a, ref) + min(ref) - 1, a <= min(ref), 0)`

Comment: Hi Julius, I would like it to be 10. You are right I wrote it confusingly, well I explained it just wrong, sorry! I edited to make it clear... hope the answers still hold, you guys are just too fast answering! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every value of `a` we find the closest value of `ref` which is greater than or equal to `a` if it is present or else return 0.

```
sapply(a, function(x) ifelse(any(x >= ref), max(ref[which(x >= ref)]), 0))
#[1]  0  0  0  0  5  6  7  8  9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10.......
```

---

As suggested by @Sotos we can use nested `replace` or `ifelse` to do the same without loops

```
#Option 1
replace(replace(a, a < min(ref), 0), a > max(ref), max(ref))

#Option 2
ifelse(a < min(ref), 0, ifelse(a > max(ref), max(ref), a))
```

Comment: I think a nested `ifelse` (or `replace`) eliminates the loop... i.e. `replace(replace(a, a < min(ref), 0), a > max(ref), max(ref))`

Answer (score 3):

We can try

```
replace(findInterval(a, ref) + min(ref) - 1, a <= min(ref), 0) 
[#1]  0  0  0  0  0  6  7  8  9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

---

Or another option is `pmin/pmax`

```
out <- pmin(a, max(ref))
out[out < min(ref)] <- 0
```

which can also be written in a single line with

```
pmin(a, max(ref)) * (a >= min(ref))
```

Comment: I think your result is a little different because I edited the question to "greater or equal" but thanks!

Comment: @JuanC Thanks for notifying the changes.  I updated with some options

Comment: Thanks! The pmin option is very direct! It took me a while to understand the one line trick... :)  Guess the T/F boolean values are 1 and 0 when it comes to multiplying!